# Returning image with threading in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit

Hi I'm working through the Stanford iOS development class.  I have a question regarding threading.  I understand UIKit calls should be handled by the main thread.  I was wondering if something like this is legal?

```
- (UIImage *)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)sender imageForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    FlickrPhotoAnnotation *fpa = (FlickrPhotoAnnotation *) annotation;
    NSURL *url = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:fpa.photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatSquare];

    __block UIImage *image;
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQ = dispatch_queue_create("download queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQ, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if (data) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            });
        }
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQ);
    return image;
}
```

or I should just return NSData and handle all the threading in the calling method?

Thanks

Comment: With just a quick look-over, I'd say it's perfect.

Comment: Look more closely. How can you return an image from this method, when neither of the two `dispatch_async` calls have finished yet?

Comment: If he made is dispatch_sync, it would wait until completion, no?

Comment: Yes, but then *why bother* with dispatch queues at all? You might as well just run the code as it is. If you have a method designed to return a value synchronously, you can't magically sprinkle threading and dispatch queues on it to make it asynchronous.

Comment: ^- Commenter above is absolutely right. Your threading code is currently redundant. The logic, sans-queues, is perfectly sound and will execute appropriately. You really only want to rely on threads for blocks that MUST be executed concurrently, or single-file (via a serial queue). Threading the results of the request (which is what you are doing), rather than the request block itself, is an inefficient usage of threads, as you need more speed in "getting" the data rather than "setting" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't do what you want.

You are putting an asynchronous block into a queue, and then immediately returning from the method. You are not guaranteed that the block will actually run before you return -- in fact, the odds are that it won't.

So you'll return the current value of `image`. Since you didn't initialize it, it's probably garbage. Whoever calls this method will try to use a garbage pointer to an image, and (if you're lucky) crash.  If you had initialized it to nil:

```
__block UIImage *image = nil;
```

that would be a little more polite.

The problem here is: your method must return a `UIImage`, so you must wait for the time it takes to make a fully constructed `UIImage` before you return. There is zero benefit to doing this on some other thread -- you're still waiting the same amount of time, and switching threads just adds overhead.

In order to load the image in a usefully asynchronous way, you need some way to asynchronously tell the caller when the image is done loading, via a callback to a delegate method or block. For example, look at `NSURLConnection` in Foundation. It has an older method that calls back via a delegate, and a newer method (`+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`) that calls back via a block.

Comment: yeah that's what i was thinking.. I just ended up returning NSData

Answer (score 0):

I concur with CodaFi's comment.  Actually, images can be created off the main thread.  UIView creation and manipulation must be done on the main thread, but UIImage is not a UIView though.  Furthermore, the runtime is likely to give you a warning or error if you try to manipulate the displaying UI on another thread (it did for me when I accidentally updated a UITableView on another thread).

Comment: Images created off the main thread had better be CGImages then, because UIKit is pretty anal-retentive about threading.

Comment: Not really. UIKit only checks for (and complains about) threading errors in a few cases. The rest of the time it happily crashes, hangs, or drives off a cliff.

Comment: @CodaFi Oh...I create nearly 8000 UIImages (10 or so at a time) for one of my tables and all of them are off the main thread :-S. It has never crashed even once. However, if the agreed upon standard is that everything starting with UI must be done on the main thread I can accept that.