# Write to NSString in block iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got stucked when learning blocks.

I have a function returns a NSString* myString.
And in the block I have to write to the string, so I added __block in front of it when defining it.

It looks all fine in the block -- I was able to write to it.
But when returning it, it shows error: use of undeclared identifier 'myString'.

I'm thinking it's because no one point to myString strongly after the block. Correct?
But what can I do the fix it?

```
- (NSString *)fetchString{
    __block NSString *myString;
    SLRequest *aRequest =  [....];
    [aRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse   *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *myArray=[NSArray array];
    myArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
    myString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }];
    return myString;
}
```

Comment: As @KurtRevis mentioned, please give us a code sample. Debugging a code via a story is hard.

Comment: @KurtRevis Sorry about that, i added the code.

Comment: @nembleton Sorry about that, i added the code.

Comment: @Joe: Why do you say that?

Comment: Is it a compiler warning? Can you please put a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax slightly wrong. You missed the closing bracket in the call to `-performRequestWithHandler:`.

(There also is no point initializing `myArray` to `[NSArray array]`, since you immediately set it to a different value.)

```
- (NSString *)fetchString{
    __block NSString *myString;
    SLRequest *aRequest = [....];
    [aRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSArray *myArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
        myString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }];
    return myString;
}
```

You'll find that this code doesn't actually work, but that's a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069243/1218876).

Comment: That's just me mistyped it. I can run the code, it's just after return, myString becomes undeclared identifier.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean? Is the compiler still giving you a warning or error saying "undeclared identifier"? (I didn't see any warnings or errors when I compiled it.)  Or is something else happening? Like I said at the end, this code won't actually work the way you want it to, and if you follow the link, you'll see a similar answer that explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with these lines:

```
[aRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse   *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
      NSArray *myArray=[NSArray array];
      myArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
      myString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

It should be:

```
[aRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse   *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
      NSArray *myArray=[NSArray array];
      myArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
      myString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }];
```

You missed to close the block.